# use inputbox as excel range

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like the user to input a range of cells such as A1:Z26. I've tried adding quotations, I've tried have 2 inputboxes, one for beginning and end of the range. But it errors out everytime with: 'method range of object_global failed'

I know it's a simple syntax issue (I think) so can anyone point me in the right direction in terms of how to have the user input a range that works in the `set rng = range(msg)`

```
Sub iterationLoop()

Dim rng As Range, iteration As Range

msg = "What is the range you'd like to look at: (e.g. A1:B2)"
InputBox (msg)
Set rng = Range(msg)

For Each iteration In rng
iteration.Select
If iteration = vbNullString Then
iteration = "add value"
MsgBox ("Cell: " & Selection.Address & " has no value")
End If

Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

aAdd

```
Dim rngstr as string
```

Then with the inputbox use this:

```
rngstr = inputbox(msg)
set rng = Range(rngstr)
```

Comment: Well played, Scott. Works. Thank you.

Comment: @JosephErickson glad I could help

Answer (score 5):

`Application.InputBox` allows you to specify the input type. Type 8 corresponds to a range. This will allow the user to either select the range with a mouse or type it in manually:

```
Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select by mouse or enter (e.g. A1:B2) the range you'd like to look at:", Type:=8)
    MsgBox rng.Address
End Sub
```

If you intend your code to be used by others, you should probably wrap the `Application.InputBox` call in some error-handling code since the above code raises a run-time error if the user presses `Cancel`. Something like:

```
On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select by mouse or enter (e.g. A1:B2) the range you'd like to look at:", Type:=8)
    If Err.Number > 0 Then
        MsgBox "No Range Selected"
        Exit Sub
    End If
On Error GoTo 0
```

(though you might want to do something more useful than just quitting the sub)

Comment: This is much better than using an Inputbox. Adding a `Selection.Address` as a default address is worth considering